# Efficient algorithm to prove that a polynomial ideal contains 1

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, computational-geometry, computer-algebra, ideals

I have the following problem:
Suppose to have an ideal $I\triangleleft k[x_1,...,x_n]$ defined by generators. There exists an efficient algorithm (perhaps more efficient than calculating the Groebner basis) to determine if $1\in I$? More precisely i'm dealing with the following case:
$$ I=(f_1(x_1,...,x_n),...,f_{n+1}(x_1,...,x_n))$$
so it is in some sense "overdetermined" and is expected to have an empty zero-set. But how can be sure about that without about that without computing Groebner basis which is a very hard problem for high values of $n$?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: We can suppose to be in the simplest non-trivial case in which $\deg(f_i)=2$

Comment: Not sure about efficiency, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Macaulay's_resultant